# Switch can't connect to controller in Mininet

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker

I am having trouble connecting the spring boot app to mysql.
I use Docker, SpringBoot, Mysql.(not use Docker compose)

when i command "docker build -t springbootmysql .", error occurred
The error is below.

```
2023-01-06 00:42:24 2023-01-05 16:42:24.864  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-01-06 00:42:24 2023-01-05 16:42:24.867  WARN 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2023-01-06 00:42:25 2023-01-05 16:42:25.935 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
2023-01-06 00:42:25 
2023-01-06 00:42:25 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2023-01-06 00:42:25 
2023-01-06 00:42:25 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2023-01-06 00:42:25     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
2023-01-06 00:42:24 Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
2023-01-06 00:42:25     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
2023-01-06 00:42:25     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
2023-01-06 00:42:25     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
2023-01-06 00:42:25     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
2023-01-06 00:42:25     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
2023-01-06 00:42:25     at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
2023-01-06 00:42:25     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
202
```

application.properties is bellow.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/spring_boot_todo
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=xxxx
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Database is below.

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+     |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| spring_boot_todo   |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
```

Docker names are below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXjzE.png)

I appreciate for your help.

i checked the application.properties...

Comment: Why is `docker build` trying to connect to a database?  Can you remove that part of your image-build process?

Comment: Thank you for information.
Could you tell me how can i remove the part?
or Could you share a reference?

Comment: You don't seem to have included any of your application code in the question, so it's very hard to say.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?